# Single page display in HTML rendering : SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report. I am using grouping and my report is having n number of pages.
Is it possible to have the html display of the report in a single page with out page break and the exported version( pdf, excel) have the page break).  Any idea. Please share some thoughts.

Thanks in advance 
Anna

Answer (score 16):

Short answer: Set the **InteractiveHeight = 0**

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701.aspx):

> Soft page breaks are calculated at run
>   time by the control. Although it is
>   not recommended, you can disable soft
>   page breaks by setting
>   **InteractiveHeight** to 0.
>
> **InteractiveHeight** and **InteractiveWidth**
>   are used by the HTML rendering
>   extension to provide the equivalent of
>   **PageHeight** and **PageWidth**. Because the
>   HTML output format dynamically resizes
>   a report to accommodate drilldown,
>   drillthrough, and show/hide features,
>   the report server uses different
>   properties to support pagination on
>   dynamic pages.

**EDIT Comment Answer:**
In the Layout mode, bring up **Properties panel**. At the top of the Properties panel is a drop down to select which control's properties you are looking at, select **Report** You will then find “Interactive Size” that includes Interactive Height property.

Comment: Where can i find this property

Comment: Edited answer for this question

Comment: Thanks for the location. I was about to start throwing things at my monitor because I couldn't find it :)

Answer (score 2):

What version of SSRS? 2008 lets you specify a different page size for interactive and regular paper (ie the html version will render different than say PDF).

Comment: +1; This answer had a -1 vote, but seemed like a legitimate question to me. In SSRS 2005 there is an "InteractiveHeight" tag available on the report element and it can be set to zero. In SSRS 2008 the report will not run if that tag is included.