# SSRS- How can I eliminate page breaks within an email body?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have several SSRS '08 reports that look great when viewed as a web page or exported to the various formats.  Recently, someone wanted a data driven subscription to go out for the report.  No prob.  They were adamant that they did not want the report attached to the email or to link to the report from the email.  No prob.  Unfortunately, the email body containing the report contents has page breaks at regular intervals.  Problem.

Is there a way to conditionally have page breaks, so that I can prevent them from showing up in the email?

Thanks for any tips.  (I googled for a solution, but if there is one, I didn't use the right search terms.)

-Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MHTML rendering extension (probably the one you're using if you're embedding reports in emails) supports the disabling of soft page breaks using the "`interactive height`" report property.

Have a peek at this question for more details:

[Single page display in HTML rendering : SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511666/single-page-display-in-html-rendering-ssrs)

Comment: An updated documentation page would be https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-behaviors-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a question related to this: They were adamant that they did not want the report attached to the email or to link to the report from the email.

How do I do this? How do I include the report in the email body?
Can this be done in SSRS 2005?